# Calling Java web service from .Net

Tags: java, .net, web-services

I need to call Java web service from .Net application and that web service should accept the parameters from .Net but am not sure about the procedure. If anyone have some idea then please let me know.

Comment: A web service is a web service is a web service. The implementation language is irrelevant. This question is really `How do I call a web service from .Net?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the WSDL first, then using Eclipse (I would suggest Netbeans) you generate/create the Stubs and call the service. It is really nothing fancy at all. Once you have the WSDL the rest (how you generate the classes using Netbeans) is really covered a lot online.

Answer (score 2):

.NET web service is SOAP web service. Just get WSDL, generate stubs and use it.